# Image URL that does not end with .jpg not display in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an image URL like this: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/witcher/images/8/86/Tw3-abelard.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20171014085335&format=original

When I tried to put that into the *src* of the *img* in React the image didn't display. It showed after I deleted all the part after the *.jpg* but the image is so blurry.

Any help on what I am supposed to do to display image from Wikia without modifying my own CSS?

Answer (score 0):

.jpg files do not scale. If the default size of the picture.jpg is 10x10 and you try to scale it to 100x100, then it will go blurry as you described. If you want a scalable picture, use .svg files instead.

Comment: The original image size in the URL without the parts behind .jpg is actually larger than my site's image though. I think there must be something else in that URL that scaled down the image